# How to exclude part of code from being hot reloaded in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using [flutter dropbox client](https://github.com/mix1009/FlutterDropbox) and it needs some init code to be run only once per app session otherwise it crashes whole application. However while in debug mode - it calls more than once after each hot restart.

Is there anyway to prevent part of code from being called when doing hot restart? I tried to set global variable before `main()` func and checking later if flag was set or not - but it also being reset when doing hot restart.

Comment: Exists some tricks by gradle (using custom tasks) or code where on of those might be: You can save some id on client/app using something like SharedPreferences or localstorage (if there exist your id then bypass certain code otherwise go ahead).

Answer (score 2):

When doing `hot restart` it resets everything including global variables. What it doesn't reset though is data that are stored locally inside the device. You can do that using the [`shared_preferences package`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Shared preferences stores data into a platform-specific location that is only usable by your app.

When your init is run, you can store a value into your shared prefs:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 await prefs.setBool('example', true);
 //this will store the bool value 'true' into a key labelled as 'example'
```

So before running your init, you can first check if that exist.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final bool example = prefs.getBool('example') ?? false;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
   if (!example) async {
     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     await prefs.setBool('example', true);
    }
}
```

Now if you want to reset that data, you can do so by adding this code or creating a temporary button somewhere inside your app that will execute this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.remove('example'); // deletes 'example' value from shared prefs platform
or
await prefs.clear(); //deletes all values saved in shared prefs platform.
```